Handling REINVITES using SipSorcery
I’m writing a program that is making calls to a Cisco phone using a SIP server.
Currently after 15 minutes it sends a reinvite and from what I can see in the logs replaces the audio track.
How can I handle the reinvites so that it won’t change anything?
I thought the issue was that the sip server was choosing different ports but after setting the sip transport to use the same ports it still doesn’t work

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
